# Replace Android Application on Playstore with Same Package Name and Keystore?

Tags: android, react-native, apk, google-play-console

My application is already on Playstore, which was developed in Java but now I have a new APK generated through Reactive Native code base using same Package Name and Keystore. Will playstore accept this new APK as an update of previous one or this will be treated as a new application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what, if the apk is having same package name and signed with the same key store file, play store will accept it and remember to increment the version code used in previous release.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same key store file, but the same certificate/private key. A key store file can contain multiple certificates with private keys. The hint about the version code is good, that one you can easily forget when starting from scratch with a new app.